# How to update an R script with information from R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have this Shiny script:

```
library(shiny)
source("oss_datamanip.R")
# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Prime Awards Analysis for the OSS Team"),
    sidebarPanel(fluidRow(
        column(12, textInput("text", h4("Please enter a DUNS number: "), 
                             value = "Enter text...")),
        column(12, textInput("text", h4("Please enter the file path where you would like your output to be saved: "), 
                             value = "Enter text...")))),
    mainPanel(textOutput("duns"),
              textOutput("file_path")),
    actionButton("script", "Run the Script")
)


# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session){
    observe({
        user.input <<- input$duns
        output.dir <<- input$file_path
    })
    source("oss_datamanip.R")
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and I want to have the user input from the Shiny app update the R script before it runs. Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is it possible? Almost certainly. Advisable? It depends ... but in general, user-input changing *code* is often called *code injection* and is a common attack vector for malware, viruses, etc ... and even though you think you can do it safely for now, I suggest that the future maintainability of the app will be extremely difficult, and troubleshooting user-injected code introduces troubleshooting problems. But ultimately we cannot really advise with specifics since it isn't clear what `oss_datamanip.R` looks like or how you expect user input to change things.

Comment: Could I just copy and paste my R code into the server logic and use the user inputs that way?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do with or to the data. And I'll be honest, there are several (inferred) indicators here (`<<-`, scope-breach; `input$file_path` instead of `shiny::fileInput(...)`; and your requested code-injection) suggests you have no experience with `shiny`. This isn't bad and not meant as a ding (you need to start somewhere), but I think it might be better at the moment for you to explain the overall purpose of this app (e.g., *"with a user-provided file, filter by DUN and show **this**"*) so we can suggest better strategies.